# pandas dataframe take elements from a list column len >1 and check the flag status and update the group id of the same row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Input dataframe

```
data = {
'Id' : ['41','79','80','81','76','77','78','37','48','83','84','85','2','3','4','73'],
'Gid' : ['G5','G70','G71','G72','G43','G44','G69','G18','G24','G83','G84','G85','G18','G2','G3','G3'],
'PFlag' : ['Processed','','','','','','','','Processed','','Processed','','Processed','','','Processed'],
'Flag_list': [['41', '42', '68'],['79'],['80'],['81', '79', '80'],['76'],['77'],['78'],['37', '68', '7'],['48', '41'],['83'],['84'],['85', '83', '84'],['2','33'],['3'],['4','73'],['73']],
'r_id' : ['6','79','80','81','76','77','78','37','48','83','84','85','2','3','4','4']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
Out[156]: 
    Id  Gid      PFlag     Flag_list r_id
0   41   G5  Processed  [41, 42, 68]    6
1   79  G70                     [79]   79
2   80  G71                     [80]   80
3   81  G72             [81, 79, 80]   81
4   76  G43                     [76]   76
5   77  G44                     [77]   77
6   78  G69                     [78]   78
7   37  G18              [37, 68, 7]   37
8   48  G24  Processed      [48, 41]   48
9   83  G83                     [83]   83
10  84  G84  Processed          [84]   84
11  85  G85             [85, 83, 84]   85
12   2  G18  Processed       [2, 33]    2
13   3   G2                      [3]    3
14   4   G3                  [4, 73]    4
15  73   G3  Processed          [73]    4
```

Output dataframe:

```
data2 = {
'Id' : ['41','79','80','81','76','77','78','37','48','83','84','85','2','3','4','73'],
'Gid' : ['G5','G72','G72','G72','G43','G44','G69','G18','G24','G85','G84','G85','G18','G2','G3','G3'],
'PFlag' : ['Processed','Processed','Processed','','','','','','Processed','Processed','Processed','','Processed','','','Processed'],
'Flag_list': [['41', '42', '68'],['79'],['80'],['81', '79', '80'],['76'],['77'],['78'],['37', '68', '7'],['48', '41'],['83'],['84'],['85', '83', '84'],['2','33'],['3'],['4','73'],['73']],
'r_id' : ['6','79','80','81','76','77','78','37','48','83','84','85','2','3','4','4']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
df2
```

Output dataframe

```
 Out[157]: 
        Id  Gid      PFlag     Flag_list r_id
    0   41   G5  Processed  [41, 42, 68]    6
    1   79  G72  Processed          [79]   79
    2   80  G72  Processed          [80]   80
    3   81  G72             [81, 79, 80]   81
    4   76  G43                     [76]   76
    5   77  G44                     [77]   77
    6   78  G69                     [78]   78
    7   37  G18              [37, 68, 7]   37
    8   48  G24  Processed      [48, 41]   48
    9   83  G85  Processed          [83]   83
    10  84  G84  Processed          [84]   84
    11  85  G85             [85, 83, 84]   85
    12   2  G18  Processed       [2, 33]    2
    13   3   G2                      [3]    3
    14   4   G3                  [4, 73]    4
    15  73   G3  Processed          [73]    4
```

Need to take the Flag_list column with greater than one element list and check against Id column and where Pflag not equal to Processed, and update the group ID, eg, 0th row is processed, flag_list row with 79, 80 are single element so don't process, when 81 comes it has 79 and 80 in its list, hence assign group_id G72 to the row with 79 and 80, similarly  row number 11th with list items [85, 83, 84]  84 is already processed hence do nothing to that row, 83 assign G85 as group_id, row 7 [68 and 7 are not present in the  Id column hence leave that..
Thanking you...

Comment: I've read this a few times and still don't really understand what you need, also I struggle to see any differences other than updating processed?  I think you need to review your data model

Comment: updating processed is based on few condition as the flag_list should be greater than 1 and the list items id above or below should not be already processed.

Comment: What is logic for row ` 9   83  G85  Processed          [83]   83` ? Why is added `Processed` ? What is logic for new values `Processed` ?

Comment: if `Gid` and `Id` then you could explode the list to rows and do a `groupby` `transform` with a `ne` to Processed

Comment: Sorry, not understand why is sometimes add `Processed` and sometimes not.

Comment: @jezrael, Processed is some thing which is already done by some other operations. hope you get me..  row 9, row 11  has three list elements has [85, 83, 84] , 84 is already processed and 83 gets the GID of row 11

Comment: hmmm, seems need some loops, check another answer for some solution, not easy vectorized this...

Comment: @jezrael, I have added comments for row9

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - It seems answer below is good, be free check it.

Comment: @jezrael, why my df results are not reflecting if i run it in a whole program.

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - hmmm, not idea, maybe bug in code below

Comment: does this usually with .loc some times happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
df['len'] = df['Flag_list'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
sub_df = df[(df['len'] > 1) & (df['PFlag'] != 'Processed')]
for i in range(sub_df.shape[0]):
    ids = sub_df['Flag_list'].iloc[i]
    cid = sub_df['Id'].iloc[i]
    gid = sub_df['Gid'].iloc[i]
    for id in ids:
        if id != cid:
            df.loc[(df['Id'] == id) & (df['PFlag'] != 'Processed'), 'Gid'] = gid
            df.loc[(df['Id'] == id) & (df['PFlag'] != 'Processed'), 'PFlag'] = 'Processed'


In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
    Id  Gid      PFlag     Flag_list r_id  len
0   41   G5  Processed  [41, 42, 68]    6    3
1   79  G72  Processed          [79]   79    1
2   80  G72  Processed          [80]   80    1
3   81  G72             [81, 79, 80]   81    3
4   76  G43                     [76]   76    1
5   77  G44                     [77]   77    1
6   78  G69                     [78]   78    1
7   37  G18              [37, 68, 7]   37    3
8   48  G24  Processed      [48, 41]   48    2
9   83  G85  Processed          [83]   83    1
10  84  G84  Processed          [84]   84    1
11  85  G85             [85, 83, 84]   85    3
12   2  G18  Processed       [2, 33]    2    2
13   3   G2                      [3]    3    1
14   4   G3                  [4, 73]    4    2
15  73   G3  Processed          [73]    4    1
```

Comment: Now, see again.@jezrael

Comment: I have modified it @jezrael

Comment: Wángxiǎochén, @王晓晨 when I do it in my whole program I am getting the same dataframe after this operation, how should get assigned  to a dataframe.

Comment: -> df.loc[(df['r_id'] == id) & (df['PFlag'] != 'Processed'), 'gid'] = gid
(Pdb) id
'4'
(Pdb) cid
4
(Pdb) type(id)
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) type(cid)
<class 'numpy.int32'>
(Pdb)  Let me try to change the types and see

Comment: I had to add, for id in ids:      id = int(id) conversion to get this work in my environment...yeah it took some time to get this sorted.. Thanking you...